# Splitting a query string on a & char to get different arguments; Python:

Tags: python, file, url, split, char

I'm looking to split the current query string on a '&' char so I can get different query arguments. From those arguments I am looking to put them into different files, i.e. p_file.txt, blog_file.txt, portfolio_file.txt, etc. I have been stuck trying to split a list of queries but it is not possible. I am open for help.

```
def parse_file():
    # Open the file for reading
    infile = open("URLlist.txt", 'r')
    # Read every single line of the file into an array of lines
    lines = infile.readlines()

    # For every line in the array of lines, do something with that line
    for line in lines:
        # The lines we get back from readlines will have a newline
        # character appended.  So, let's strip that out as we parse
        # the URL from the line into its components
        line = line.strip()
        url = urlparse(line)
        # If the url has a query component...(ie. url.query)
        if url.query:
            # ...then print it out!  We need to strip the trailing newline
            # character from the url query, because urlparse doesn't do that
            # for us.  
            queryvars = url.query
            print queryvars
            #for q in queryvars:
                 #print q
       parse_file()
```

Comment: Does `queryvars = url.query.split('&')` work?

Comment: Yes! It is splitting upon the '&' char. How would I be able to put whatever is split into different files? ex: p=49 -> p_file.txt, attachment_id = 32 -> attachment_id_file.txt

Comment: @kindall's suggestion to use parse_qs is probably better, actually.  That will give you a dictionary, e.g. `{ 'p': ['49'], 'attachment_id': ['32'] }`.  You can then iterate over that with e.g. `for key in queryvars: filename = key + '_file.txt' [...]`.

Comment: so: `url = parse_qsl(urlparse(line)[4])` `for key in url:
    p_file = key + 'p_file.txt'`

Comment: if there is a 'p=', write out to the file

Answer (score 1):

I expect you want [urlparse.parse_qs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs).